# Sharing media devices from linux to windows

Tags: windows-7, linux, networking, usb, usb-flash-drive

I want to have a raspberry pi as a USB hub in a windows network. Let me explain: we have about 10 windows PC's and we need to have access to USB media devices (like a usb stick, an android phone, a removable hard drive) from all of them. I can't plug the media device in a windows PC because there is a very high threat of having a virus infect our whole network -a risk we can't take. What we are doing so far is this: we have one of the PC's dual boot with linux and we share a specific usb port to the network. This often causes trouble and we also have 1 PC less to work.

What I want to do is have a raspberry pi just for this reason, up and ready to share any of the media devices that we could plug in.

And now my question: can you give me some resources and examples of this being done? Maybe a tutorial or something. I am not looking for something fancy, just point me to the correct direction, since I am not a linux and network veteran.

More specific: I want the raspberry pi to work without a screen, so it has to be modular to do this exact task. Load up the system, and share it's media devices to the network. We will have access to it only via SSH but since most of us working there don't even know what SSH is the system has to do everything without human interaction.

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, because the Super User is being used I am going to include a little:

***Disclaimer:** I, the poster of this answer, am not responsible for any data lost, compromised, etc. by the user whom is using this guide. Furthermore, I cannot nor will not be held responsible for any loss of system integrity with the methods below. **Continue at your own risk!***

Now with that out of the way, probably the easiest thing to do is make a Samba share of the `/media` folder, because the Raspberry Pi is set up to autocratically mount inserted media, this should work.

[Here](http://raspberrywebserver.com/serveradmin/share-your-raspberry-pis-files-and-folders-across-a-network.html) is the link I retrieved the following information for setting up Samba on the Raspberry pi:

1. You need to install the Samba runtime by using `sudo apt-get install samba samba-common-bin`
2. Next you need to edit the Samba config: `sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf`
3. Find the entries for workgroup and wins support, and set them up as follows (The name of the workgroup can be anything you want, as long as it only contains alphabetical characters, and it matches the name of the workgroup that you want to join):

```
workgroup = your_workgroup_name
wins support = yes
```

4. Add the following to the smb.conf, in the `Share Definitions` section:

```
[pihome]
   comment= Pi Home
   path=/media
   browseable=Yes
   writeable=Yes
   only guest=no
   create mask=0777
   directory mask=0777
   public=no
```

5. Now type this command in a terminal, and enter the password you want to use twice:

```
smbpasswd -a pi
```

If you have a PC or laptop connected to your workgroup, you should be able to see your Raspberry Pi in Windows Explorer under Network.

Also if you try this method and are having problems, double check that the permissions of the media folder are correctly. Or if you don't know what I mean by this, just run `sudo chown -R pi /media && sudo chmod -R 777 /media` and it might be enough to solve your problems.

I would also like to point out, while this might help prevent the USB drives from automaticly installing Windows based malware, it will not help if you run an infected file on your windows system. This method should not and will not replace an Anti-malware/Anti-virus solution.

Hope this Helps!